# How to add content below the map with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, jvectormap

Is it possible to enable some container below the map with JVectorMap? I have some links for all states which needs to appear when user clicks on state. I am new with Javascript so please help me.

For example, I have three links which needs to show when user clicks on Florida:
www.google.com
http://gis.stackexchange.com
ebay.com

How to define those links to be related to Florida? Links need to appear in the container when user clicks on that state.

Comment: Perhaps providing some more detail about what you are trying to do, like data sources, overall project, etc. would help you obtain an answer.  On the other hand, if you've come up with an answer to your question, feel free to post and accept it as an answer.

Comment: Vote for closed, too localized. The accepted answer is empty of usable content, essentially just "ask elsewhere", and while the same query did get asked at Jvectormap's hub, it is unanswered and closed there too (https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues/80).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to post this [in the issues for jvectormap](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues) rather than here.